# How to set the numeric hexadecimal colour in jquery color picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, color-picker

I used JQuery colorpicker in my php page but when I set the color in javascript then it doesn't work.

here is my html code:

```
<div class="group_col grp_col_3">
    <div class="list_field">
        <label>Link Hover</label>
         <div class="color_field">
           <span class="colpr" style="background:#647993;"></span>
             <input name="style_link_hover_color" id="style_link_hover_color" type="text" data-value="647993" class="form-control&#x20;field&#x20;color-box&#x20;adv-settings" value="647993">    
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code of javascript:

```
$(input).each(function (e) {
    var hex = '647993';
    $(this).val(hex);
    $(this).colpickSetColor(hex);
});
```

how do I set this type of color in javascript?

Comment: which color picker are you using?

Comment: http://www.jq22.com/demo/colpick-jQuery-Color-Picker-master/

Comment: how about using  `$(this).css('background-color', '#'+hex);`

Comment: No if i use $(this).css('background-color', '#'+hex); then it makes overall input field gray but i want only span colour should gray

Comment: you may see example "HEX textfield using onChange callback" of above link

Comment: Please create a fiddle for same.

Comment: Sorry i don't make fiddle but i update my code,you may check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105770/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-muhammad-arif).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that i used to fix above issue

```
$(input).each(function (e) {
 var hex = 647993;
 if(!isNaN(hex)){
    hex = hex.toString();
}
$(this).val(hex);
$(this).colpickSetColor(hex);
});
```

This is becuase jquery color picker not work with integer values like 647993.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the code incorrectly, trying to set the the value in the input field of the color picker. You should do this:

Add the color picker wherever you want (if you have not added):

```
<div id="picker"></div>
```

or

```
<button id="picker">Show Color Picker</button>
```

Then in the javascript, you need to:

Initialized if you had not initialize it:

```
$('#picker').colpick();
```

and then change it when you want and after it has been initialized with:

```
var hex = '647993';
$('#picker').colpickSetColor(hex, false);
```

If you want to change also the input field I think you need to set the second param to true. Please notice that the selector to change is the same that you use to initialize, and it should be an ID to avoid problems.

```
var hex = '647993';
$('#picker').colpickSetColor(hex, true);
```

Of course you need to load the script and it's CSS in the html code.